# $|A| = |B|$ Show that this function is surjective when it is one to one

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite sets with $\vert A \vert = \vert B \vert$ and $f$ be a function from $A$
to $B$. show that if $f$ is an injective (one-to-one) function then it is also a
surjective function.

Answer: i don't know if this assumption right or wrong

By contradiction that function $f$ one to one $\Rightarrow$ onto
we assume that $f$ is not onto function $\forall a \in A∶f(a)\neq b$

$\vert A\vert=\vert B\vert$,then there exist two different elements in $A$ such that have same image
 one to one function then for 
$\exists x \in A ,\exists y \in B ,f(x)=f(y)\land (x\neq y)$.

However Since $f$ is one to one function,$f(x)=f(y)$  implies $x=y$
$\exists x \in A ,\exists y\in B ,f(x)=f(y)\land (x\neq y)$.

by negation law we obtain that last statement is F(false)and we obtain contradiction
thus $f$ is onto since it's one to one.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof verification here? It would be nice to know what properties you are allowed to use in your proof. The idea of the proof is completely correct, but there are some things to improve.

For example, you should write that there exists a $b \in B$ such that $f(a) \neq b \forall a \in A$. Now there is a missing quantifier.

Also, you should maybe justify why there are two points in $x,y \in A$ which have the same image. Here, you are using both the injectivity of $f$, and something like the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401604/suppose-x-is-a-finite-set-and-f-x-to-x-is-a-function-then-f-is-injecti?rq=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose $X$ is a finite set and $f : X \to X$ is a function. Then $f$ is injective if and only if $f$ is surjective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401604/suppose-x-is-a-finite-set-and-f-x-to-x-is-a-function-then-f-is-injecti)

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ and $B$ have the same number of elements, then an injective map from $A$ to $B$ exists. Injective means that two different elements $x,y \in A$ map to two different elements $f(x),f(y) \in B$. So every element of $A$ maps to exactly one element of $B$ therefore the map is also surjective since all elements of $B$ are mapped to some element in $A$.